# Strange issue involving a RCPP pointer

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, cgal

I'm trying to wrap some **CGAL** code with **Rcpp**. I have two functions:

```
Rcpp::XPtr<Alpha_shape_3> AS_cpp(Rcpp::NumericMatrix pts) {
  // make list of points
  const int npoints = pts.ncol();
  std::list<Point3> points;
  for(int i = 0; i < npoints; i++) {
    const Rcpp::NumericVector pt_i = pts(Rcpp::_, i);
    points.push_back(Point3(pt_i(0), pt_i(1), pt_i(2)));
  }
  // compute alpha shape
  Alpha_shape_3 as(points.begin(), points.end());
  // returns R pointer
  Rcpp::XPtr<Alpha_shape_3> as_xptr(&as, false);
  return as_xptr;
}

void optimalAlpha_cpp(Rcpp::XPtr<Alpha_shape_3> as_xptr) {
  Alpha_shape_3& as = *(as_xptr.get());
  Alpha_iterator opt = as.find_optimal_alpha(1);
  Rcpp::Rcout << *opt;
}
```

In R, I do `x <- AS_cpp(mymatrix)` then I get the external pointer. Then I do `optimalAlpha_cpp(x)` and I get either a wrong result (a huge number) or a crash.

Even if you don't know what this code is doing, I can show you the strange point: if I move the contents of the second function inside the first function then this works.

```
Rcpp::XPtr<Alpha_shape_3> AS_cpp(Rcpp::NumericMatrix pts) {
  // make list of points
  const int npoints = pts.ncol();
  std::list<Point3> points;
  for(int i = 0; i < npoints; i++) {
    const Rcpp::NumericVector pt_i = pts(Rcpp::_, i);
    points.push_back(Point3(pt_i(0), pt_i(1), pt_i(2)));
  }
  // compute alpha shape
  Alpha_shape_3 as(points.begin(), points.end());
  // make R pointer
  Rcpp::XPtr<Alpha_shape_3> as_xptr(&as, false);
  // dereference the R pointer
  Alpha_shape_3& as2 = *(as_xptr.get());
  Alpha_iterator opt = as2.find_optimal_alpha(1);
  Rcpp::Rcout << *opt; // <--- THIS RESULT IS CORRECT
  // returns the R pointer
  return as_xptr;
}
```

How is it possible? Any clue?

Comment: The object pointed to seems to be disappearing between the two calls (because your object `as` disappears), but remains in scope and is accesible for the second one.  So you managed to control the pointer but not the memory pointed to.  You need to allocate with `new`, the default cleanup for an `XPtr<>` then calls `delete` on destruction.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel **sloriot** found the solution: <https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/discussions/6989>.

Comment: Yes that is what I wrote to you too: `as` disappears when the function ends (as it is just on the heap as a local variable), and you need to allocate. We all stumbled over stuff like that once or twice before.